# VBA - Get color from range object (cell)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to print the color of a cell using VBA using two different ways, the second one doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Here's the code:

```
Sub GetColors()
  ' Cell A1 has a red interior, both of these commands should print 255
  Dim r As Range

  Debug.Print Range("A1").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color ' Working - Prints 255

  ' Using ranges & indexing
  Set r = Range("A1:A5")
  ' r(1, 1) is the first element of r, and is also a range...
  Debug.Print TypeName(r(1, 1)) ' Prints Range
  ' Since r(1, 1) is a range, we should be able to get the color like before...
  r(1, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color ' Object doesn't support this property or method
End Sub
```

I don't understand why the second method doesn't work, VBA knows that `r(1, 1)` is a `Range` object so it should give `r(1, 1)` all the same properties and methods as any other `Range`. Is there something special about accessing ranges through indexes? Or am I just missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the technical term is, but you need an action on that final line. Put another `debug.print` in front and it should work.

Comment: You should use other approach, like `Debug.Print r.Cells(1, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Comment: `r(1, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` gets/sets an object property value (color) depending on which side of the equation it is located .... you have to do something with it (print it, assign it to a variable, assign to it etc. ...)  .... the way you have it written, color is a method of a range.DisplayFormat.Interior object, except that it is not a method of that object